# Draw text and make it fit inside a rectangle in GDI?

Tags: c, winapi, gdi

Is there's a function that can draw text and fit it inside a rectangle (the function will make the size of the text smaller as appropriate to make it fit or something).

I checked the parameters for [DrawText()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162498%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but I don't think it supports such a feature.

Comment: There is no GDI function that changes font size. You will have to probe sizes yourself.

Comment: The closest to the functionality you are looking for is [`DrawText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162498.aspx)'s ability to truncate the string, when supplied with either of the `DT_{WORD|PATH|END}_ELLIPSIS` format flags. This, however, does not change the **height** of a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use GetTextMetrics to check if the text fits inside the rectangle, and if it doesn't, reduce the current font size and repeat the measurement.

GetTextMetrics:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144941%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: If it *does* fit, you could then increase the size until it does not - use a decrementing delta size until your delta is sufficiently small (be warned it may not end up as "0"). Use this if you want an *exact* fit.

Answer (score 0):

There is no function doing it right away, but your can write your own using `DrawText` with `DT_CALCRECT` parameter. This parameter will only calculate size of your text and return it to you. It allows also multi line text and also checks provided maximal width you can allow text to be. So if the output rectangle - as calculated by DrawText is too large, then you must calculate it again but with smaller font, you can speed up calculations by using binary method to find the most appropriate font size.